# How to use custom Tokenizer in Hugging Face pretrained model for text summarization?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, summarization, huggingface-tokenizers

I need to make a for loop for running text summarization models as they have a maximum input limit for text summarization using `huggingface transformers`.

To execute the for loop and get its range, I need to pass tokenized input to the model and prevent it from tokenizing again inside the pipeline.

here is the code snippet:

```py
summarizer = transformers.pipeline("summarization", model = 't5-small', tokenizer = 't5-small')

tokenized_text = summarizer.tokenizer(text)
```

I need to iterate over this tokenized_text.

If I pass slices of `tokenizer_text` into `summarizer` , it will get tokenizer again. My aim is to prevent that from happening the second time.

Comment: I assume you are tokenizing your text to find the 510th token?

Comment: not a specific number. more like a variable number, which is the max length of tokenizer. so that in a for loop I can insert more input than the tokenizer can handle at a time.
Also the tokenizers are meant to be swapped hence its `tokenizer.max_length` taken as a variable.

Comment: Afaik, there is no straightforward functionality implemented that allows this. You can either inherit from the `SummarizationPipeline` and override some of its functions or split the text before.

Comment: Can you please  kindly elaborate on the code for it ?  Or share some resources?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem, please, or not yet?

Comment: Not yet, it was for a hackathon. I had to submit what I had because of the time constraint.  If you want a solution to this just as I do please do consider upvoting this question for better reach.